# How can i develop a Dual Listbox in ENYO

Tags: listbox, enyo

I want to add a dual listbox in one of the page developed using ENYO. How can i achieve this. Is there any plugin i can try for. Thanks!!!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use 2 enyo.List or enyo.Repeater kinds and have two arrays of items; one for the left side and one for the right.  Put the lists in an enyo.FittableColumns with the buttons between them.